# Can Integers be Implemented in the Toggle() Operator in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, swiftui

I am trying to figure out a workaround for the toggle() operator in SwiftUI which does not use a Boolean type variable.

The issue I'm running into is MySQL databases do not have a Bool data type... such that 'true' and/or 'false' cannot be set in the field (not as strings but the literal type which Swift accepts as boolean input).

I have attempted to use an integer, either 0 for false, or 1 for true, and have also tried typecasting but cannot figure out how to do this.

I am accessing my database using an API which generates my data in JSON format and loads in many objects, each of which need to be subject to the toggle() operator.

Does anybody know an alternate method for utilizing the toggle() operator without the Boolean data type?

Additionally - I find it very odd (and frustrating) that MySQL doesn't have a literal Bool data type. I understand 0's & 1's are more efficient... but is it possible to immediately change the value of the JSON from an integer to a boolean once I GET it from my database?

Thank you!

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. The details of a particular database (MySQL today, maybe another tomorrow) aren't something that should be at all apparenty from any of your Swift code, besides the boundary layer that deals with interfacing with the DB. You should use `Bool`.

Comment: Alexander, thank you for your response! Do you have any recommendation for modeling my data structure in the Swift environment to allow for an integer (or string) value to be used as a boolean value?

Comment: I don't know how you're interfacing with your database, but wherever you do that, you should to translation from database specific types, to/from Swift "common currency" types, like `Bool`, `Int` (which is preferred in most cases, even if negative values or large values aren't needed), `String`, `URL`, `UIImage`, etc. You should do this for all input/output mechanisms, like databases, file access, network APIs. Design your data models to be easy to use. Translate to/from other formats only as necessary at the perimeter

Comment: For example, never use a string as a file path. Perhaps `MySQL` doesn't have a concept of `URL`. When writing your model to the database, convert its URLs to strings, and save the strings. When you later read that model, immediately load in the string into a URL, and only ever operate on that within your app. Same for `Bool`, or any other unrepresentable types.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second the comment above about not exposing the particulars of any database to the rest of the code. It's best that you work with a model with `Bool`, instead of adapting `Int` to be like `Bool`.

So, to restate your question with an example, you'd want to convert a JSON object like this:

```json
{ "boolProp": 1, "otherProp": "something" }
```

into a model like this:

```
struct Model {
   var boolProp: Bool
   var otherProp: String
}
```

Unfortunately, `Codable` doesn't provide a way to customize how to decode primitive types.

You could always implement manual decoding, but it would necessitate you decoding all the properties, not just the specific `Bool` ones. So if you have lots of other properties, that's obviously not an optimal approach.

Alternatively, you could decode the integer representation of a Boolean into a private variable and provide a computed property for the `Bool` that your code can work with:

```
enum IntRepresentableBool: Int, Codable {
    case `true` = 1
    case `false` = 0
}

struct Model: Codable {

  private var _boolProp: IntRepresentableBool
  var boolProp: Bool {
     get { _boolProp == .true ? true : false }
     set { _boolProp = newValue ? .true : .false }
  }
  
  var otherProp: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case _boolProp = "boolProp"
     case otherProp
  }
}
```

With this approach, you could decode your object and use it as you expected:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
var model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: jsonData)

model.boolProp.toggle()
```